# Are commands/write operations in a repository an anti-pattern?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I've used the Repository Pattern in a few .NET projects now, but I always get back to arguing with myself about this question:

Thinking of a repository as a queryable data store, one could argue that having commands (or write operations) in a repository is a misconception, as to the [command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) principle. On the other hand, keeping the methods that have to do with the same domain objects in the same class simplifies coding and usage, and promotes the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) and [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principles.

Which different views/arguments do you have? What would Fowler or Evans say?

Comment: I think you are mixing up CQS and CQRS...

Comment: Yes, you're right - I should've referred to Command-Query Responsibility Segregation, which is applied at the architecture level, while CQS is applied at a method level.

http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/11/cqrs-la-greg-young/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, having persistence logic & references to underlying technologies like O/RMs in one place is more important than splitting by the read/write responsibility. So I combine command & queries in one concrete repository per domain aggregate root, usually with a persistence-technology specific abstract base class (Nhibernate, Entity Framework, etc).

The only time I split these up is when I am doing a complete CQRS implementation (command/query responsibility segregation) with event sourcing, i.e., when reading and writing happens in completely different areas of my code base against different data stores.